# How to show more info in a citation

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm trying to make a BibTeX entry for a computer library, which does not have one. This is all I know about it:

```
@book{intelMKL,
    title={Intel Math Kernel Library. Reference Manual},
    publisher={Intel Corporation},
    city={Santa Clara},
    country={USA},
    isbn={630813-054US},
    year={2009}
}
```

Now I'd like to show as much of that as possible in the references, but as it is now, it is only showing:

> Intel Math Kernel Library. Reference Manual, Intel Corporation, 2009

How do I best modify the BibTeX to show more fields? Maybe I'm doing it all wrong, I'm not so good with this. I'm using:

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked:

> How do I best modify the BibTeX to show more fields?

Don't modify BibTeX. Instead, modify the entry. E.g., you could move the material in the `city`, `country`, and `isbn` fields to a field called `note`, as the `ieeetr` bibliography style recognizes the `note` field type and will typeset its contents. (The `ieeetr` style does *not* recognize fields named `city`, `country`, and `isbn`, and that's why their contents aren't being typeset.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{intel-alt,
    title={Intel Math Kernel Library. Reference Manual},
    publisher={Intel Corporation},
    note = {Santa Clara, USA. ISBN 630813-054US},
    year={2009},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @barbarabeeton has pointed out in a comment, the `ieeetr` bibliography style does recognize the field `address`. Thus, an alternative form of the bib entry could be:

```
@book{intel-alt,
    title    = {Intel Math Kernel Library. Reference Manual},
    publisher= {Intel Corporation},
    address  = {Santa Clara, USA},
    note     = {ISBN 630813-054US},
    year     = {2009},
}
```

Comment: `ieeetr.bst` *does* list `address` among the recognized field types, so that might be a better distinction.  it may also give a different order of elements in the output entry.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for this. I've posted an addendum to incorporate your suggestion.